# [ROS2][dashing] is there any roslibpy-like lib for ros2 frontend?

Tags: ros, ros2, call-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a way for a non-ROS machine (my local computer) to access the ROS2 robot(Rasberry pi) to, for example, call the service. Is there any method to do so? I found a similar [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/314562/best-approach-for-ros2-creating-a-webfrontend/), but it's about a year ago.

Since I confirmed that both `ros-dashing-rosbridge-server` and `tf2` are already available in ROS2, I tried to use `roslibpy`. Seems it can connect to the ros2 without any problem. I am wondering if it is the proper way to use `roslibpy` for my purpose?

Below is what I did, however, I got `FieldTypeMismatchException` error.

I followed the [online examples](https://github.com/gramaziokohler/roslibpy/blob/master/docs/files/ros-service-call-set-bool.py) to create a service '/set_ludicrous_speed', 'std_srvs/srv/SetBool'.

```
import roslibpy

def handler(request, response):
    print('Setting speed to {}'.format(request['data']))
    response['success'] = True
    return True

client = roslibpy.Ros(host='10.3.xxx.xxx', port=9090)

service = roslibpy.Service(client, '/set_ludicrous_speed', 'std_srvs/srv/SetBool')
service.advertise(handler)
print('Service advertised.')

client.run_forever()
client.terminate()
```

While, when I try to call the service like below:

```
import roslibpy

client = roslibpy.Ros(host='10.3.xxx.xxx', port=9090)
client.run()

service = roslibpy.Service(client, '/set_ludicrous_speed', 'std_srvs/srv/SetBool')
request = roslibpy.ServiceRequest({'data': True})

result = service.call(request)
print('Service response: {}'.format(result))

client.terminate()
```

I got error like this, but I can see the node is connected and the service is created:

```
[INFO] [rosbridge_websocket]: Client disconnected. 0 clients total.
[INFO] [rosbridge_websocket]: Client connected. 1 clients total.
[INFO] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client 1] Advertised service /set_ludicrous_speed.
[INFO] [rosbridge_websocket]: Client connected. 2 clients total.
[ERROR] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client 2] [id: call_service:/set_ludicrous_speed:1] call_service FieldTypeMismatchException: std_srvs/SetBool_Request message requires a boolean for field data, but got a <class 'bool'>
```

Any idea what did I miss? Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343196/%5Bros2%5D%5Bdashing%5D-is-there-any-roslibpy-like-lib-for-ros2-frontend?/) by [lin404](https://answers.ros.org/users/50033/lin404/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2020-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-04**:
You tagged this `ros2` and `dashing`. Afaik, `roslibpy` and `rosbridge` are ROS 1 libraries/nodes.

Could you please clarify?

**Comment by [lin404](https://answers.ros.org/users/50033/lin404/) on 2020-02-04**:
@gvdhoorn I am sorry for the confusion. Actually, I need a frontend (ideally in python) to access ROS2-dashing env. Then I found this [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/314562/best-approach-for-ros2-creating-a-webfrontend/). It mentioned [Robot web tool](http://robotwebtools.org/tools.html#libraries) and [rosbridge_suite](https://github.com/ros2/rosbridge_suite/tree/ros2_ament_cmake). Since seems both `ros-dashing-rosbridge-server` and `tf2` are already available in ROS2, so I thought maybe I could use `roslibpy` to access the ROS2 dashing. Seems my whole approach was wrong. >.<

I have changed my question. Thank you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-04**:\

> Seems my whole approach was wrong. >.<

Well, I'm not saying that's the case, I just wanted to make sure I understood the context correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I SOLVED it! 
Sum up, `roslibpy` can be used to connect to a ROS2 machine, as well as `rosbridge`. 
`FieldTypeMismatchException` here is just a bug in `rosbridge`. It's caused by python version (>3).  
Here is my [commit](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/pull/455/commits/81af650a990e1a7f390a776341a5f20ec37910cb) to  the bug.  
A small bug, very simple to fix, but cost me much time to find it.

---

Originally posted by [lin404](https://answers.ros.org/users/50033/lin404/) with karma: 60 on 2020-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-07**:
Nice.

Thanks for reporting, investigating and fixing it!